# Finding last pattern occurance in string

Tags: text-processing, grep

I'm trying to parse log file lines for IP addresses with grep -o '[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}' and would like to extract only last IP address in every given line.

Example of two lines to parse:

```
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 78.41.207.101:5237;branch=z9hG4bK-577783956;rport=5237
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 127.0.0.1:5079;branch=z9hG4bK-1014230957;rport=5079;received=194.126.22.146
```

I'm getting:

```
78.41.207.101
127.0.0.1
194.126.22.146
```

What I would like to get:

```
78.41.207.101
194.126.22.146
```

I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this sed

```
sed -E 's/.*[^0-9](([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}).*/\1/' infile
```

---

Explain :

-E to use extanded regular expression.
Without -E you must write the command this way

```
sed 's/.*[^0-9]\(\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}\).*/\1/' infile
```

(([0-9]{1,3}.){3}[0-9]{1,3}) is the same RE as yours.

```
<-------> !  
    1     3 time
```

'[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}'

<---------><---------><--------->

```
   1       2       3
```

The first part .*[^0-9] is greedy.
It match all it can before the last regex in the line.
The last .* match the end of the line.

Comment: We prefer answers that contain some *explanation,* and are not just a command.

Answer (score 0):

I like using awk in such cases:

```
$ awk '{print $NF}' FPAT="[0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}" file1
78.41.207.101
194.126.22.146
```

`FPAT` is used to define what a field consists of (identical to your grep -o pattern)
`$NF` is the last field of each line

Comment: Wow, it's so simple with awk.

Answer (score 0):

Most regexp machinery use greedy patterns, i.e., they match as much as they can. So something like `^.*[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+` will match *up to and including* the last IPv4 address. Capture that.